# SQL Server 2000 join with count condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2000

I am joining multiple tables. With one of my joins (1 to many) I want to show results only if the joined table has at least one row where a certain value exists.

This example excludes the other joins, so for simplicity's sake:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Contact c
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
```

A Contact can have many Roles.  I want to show all roles for contacts, but only get the Contacts where at least one role has RoleID = 4.  I have tried a few things but no success thus far.  If it matters, this is on SQL Server 2000.

I have expanded the scope of the problem into this new question:  [SQL Server 2000 condition on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839917/sql-server-2000-condition-on-joined-table)

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. This means it no longer gets any updates... _not even critical security patches!_ It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using it. Upgrading this server is job #1.

Comment: I could not agree with you more, and that server is due for upgrade by another department later in the year.

Comment: I have expanded the scope the problem into this new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839917/sql-server-2000-condition-on-joined-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the join twice, once where you limit to ID 4 as a filter, and again to pull in all roles:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Contact c
INNER JOIN  --if a Contact does not match any Roles with ID 4, this join will exclude that contact from the results
    Role rt /*role temp*/ ON rt.ContactID = c.ID AND rt.RoleId = 4        
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
```

This does make one assumption that was not explicitly stated in the question. While a Contact can have many roles, this presumes a contact will not be assigned the same role more than once.

Comment: Good point, and, actually, a contact may have a role more than once, as there are other properties on the role record that would differentiate the same roles for a given contact.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to wait for the server upgrade, as newer versions of Sql Server will allow you to use the APPLY operator to make the 1st JOIN, which you can use to limit yourself to one result.

Comment: Well, that isn't really an option at this point.  I am using this query to assist in a task, and that task is already past due!  Thx for your input, it may lead me to a solution.

Comment: Your solution works, but when I bring in the other tables to join I am running into issues where not all contacts returned have a roleID = 4, but some of them do.  You have provided a working answer to the question asked and therefore deserve credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Contact c
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Role 
             WHERE RoleID = 4
             AND ContactID = c.ID);
```

Comment: Your solution ALSO works, but when I bring in the other tables to join I am running into issues where not all contacts returned have a roleID = 4, but some of them do.  You have provided a working answer to the question asked and therefore deserve credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try

```
SELECT 
    c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Contact c
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID group by c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName having min(r.RoleID) = 4
```

Comment: This answer ONLY returns roles where RoleID = 4, and no other roles.

Comment: You can use like that

SELECT 
    c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Contact c
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID where c.ID in (SELECT 
    r.ContactID
FROM 
    Role r group by r.ContactID having min(r.RoleID) = 4))

Comment: RoleID begins at 1, and a Contact could have a RoleID's of 1, 3, 4, 22, etc.  So, it seems that "having min(r.RoleID) = 4)" would omit contacts with RoleID < 4?