# SQL Server 2000 condition on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

The following is a simplified example of something I've been trying to solve for a couple days and is related to a question I previously asked, but I have increased the problem scope in this question.

In this example, an Issue can have multiple Contacts, and a Contact can have multiple Roles.

I want to show results only if at least one Contact has a Role with RoleID = 4.  This means I want to see all Contacts and Roles for an Issue, but the Issue must have at least one Contact where RoleID = 4.

```
SELECT 
    i.ID, i.Date, c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Issue i
INNER JOIN
    Contact c ON c.IssueID = i.ID
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
```

If it matters, this is on SQL Server 2000.  And, yes, I know that SQL Server 2000 is no longer supported, way past end of life, dangerous and irresponsible to use, etc, etc; but the server is due for upgrade by another department later in the year and it's use is beyond my control for now.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show results only if at least one Contact has a Role with
>   RoleID = 4. This means I want to see all Contacts and Roles for an
>   Issue, but the Issue must have at least one Contact where RoleID = 4.

I would use `EXISTS` to filter the list of issues.

```
SELECT 
    i.ID, i.Date, c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM 
    Issue i
INNER JOIN
    Contact c ON c.IssueID = i.ID
INNER JOIN
    Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Contact c1 ON c1.IssueID = i.ID
    INNER JOIN
    Role r1 ON r1.ContactID = c1.ID
    AND r1.RoleID = 4
)
```

Not judging you on the SQL 2000 thing but.... do you have a plan to get off? It's pretty simple nowadays to download a free Express edition and have a go at upgrading or even try a free cloud solution

Comment: You probably didn't read that far, but it is due for upgrade by another department later in the year and it's use is beyond my control for now.

Comment: Oh you're right - I broke my own rule and didn't read properly!

Comment: Just noticed a few errors in my code - it's worth trying now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the issues using aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT i.ID
FROM Issue i INNER JOIN
     Contact c
     ON c.IssueID = i.ID INNER JOIN
     Role r
     ON r.ContactID = c.ID
GROUP BY i.ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.RoleId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

If you need the additional columns, you can join those back in.

Comment: This sort of works, every returned record has RoleID = 4.  Other Roles are not in the results nor are other Contacts for Issue that don't have RoleID = 4.

Comment: @Kershaw . . . As explained, this returns the issues that meet your condition.  You can join back other tables if you need additional information.

Comment: @Gordon...what I mean is that I only get roles where RoleID=4.  I need all roles for all Contacts where at least one Contact in the Issue has RoleID=4.

Comment: @Kershow . . . This returns *issues* that have at least one role of "4".

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
Just add two more joins to same Contact / Role tables + DISTINCT to remove the duplicates if there are multiple contacts with RoleID = 4:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.ID, i.Date, c.Name, r.RoleID, r.RoleName
FROM Issue i
   INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.IssueID = i.ID
   INNER JOIN Role r ON r.ContactID = c.ID
   INNER JOIN Сontact c2 ON c2.IssueID = i.ID
   INNER JOIN Role r2 ON r2.ContactID = c2.ID AND r2.RoleID = 4
```